# ¿Cómo generar una subconsulta con el query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Como puedo pasar la siguiente consulta anidada a laravel con Eloquent?

```
select AVG(total_puntos)
FROM
(
SELECT uca.user_id, SUM(uca.points_user) as total_puntos
from user_category_activity as uca
join client_user as cu on cu.user_id = uca.user_id
where cu.client_id = 3 
GROUP BY uca.user_id
) as promedio_total
```

Hasta el momento tengo esto (consulta interna), me hace falta el promedio:

```
   $sumapuntos=DB::table('user_category_activity as uca')
    ->select(DB::raw('uca.user_id, sum(uca.points_user) as points_user'))
    ->join('client_user as cu', 'cu.user_id', '=', 'uca.user_id')
    ->where('cu.client_id', $c->client_id)
    ->groupBy('uca.user_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hola ¿nos compartes si has intentado algo por favor?

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy abstracta, procura agregar tus modelos.

Comment: @BetaM, tengo la consulta interna, la de la suma:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase **`Builder`** ubicada en:

**`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php`**

Posee un método denominado [**`fromSub`**](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_fromSub) que nos permite establecer el **`from`** de una subconsulta

Lo que hacemos es:

- Seleccionar el promedio de una columna X
- Dentro del método mencionado al inicio de la respuesta pasamos:

  - Una función a partir de la cual construimos la consulta interna
  - El alias que recibirá esta consulta interna

    ```
               DB::query()->selectRaw('AVG(total_puntos)')
                          ->fromSub(function ($query) {
                              $query->selectRaw('uca.user_id, SUM(uca.points_user) as total_puntos')
                                  ->from('user_category_activity')
                                  ->join('client_user', 'client_user.user_id', '=', 'user_category_activity.user_id')
                                  ->where('client_user.client_id', 3)
                                  ->groupBy('user_category_activity.user_id')
                          }, 'promedio_general')->get();
    ```
- Este método fue agregado al query builder desde la versión 5.6 del framework, (*esto lo puedes comprobar en el github del mismo*)